# gpg: Bad signature

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gpg, pgp

I'm trying to sign a public PGP key but am encountering a 'Bad signature' error:

```
gpg --edit-key someone@somedomain.com
...
gpg> sign
...
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "My User <myuser@mydomain.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 12345678, created 2012-01-01
```

I enter my passphrase then get:

```
gpg: checking created signature failed: Bad signature
gpg: signing failed: Bad signature
gpg: signing failed: Bad signature
```

I've done some searching online but can only find old, unrelated posts or ones relating to smart cards, which I'm not using.

I'm running gnupg 2.0.25-1 on an Arch Linux box.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: You're probably better off asking on the GnuPG mailing list to also reach the developers, as this seems like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Jens.  I'll do that and add a solution here, if one is forthcoming.